# Whats the proper way to do concatenation in PHP?

Tags: php

I understand that there is a difference between single quoted and double quoted strings. 
And after reading other stackOverfow questions and looking at [this article](http://phplens.com/lens/php-book/optimizing-debugging-php.php) it seems most people agree that the performance gain of using single quotes is negligible.

As a new PHP user *always* using double quotes seems the most logic and least confusing way. But why do people still split their double quoted links?

```
<?php

 $a = '12345';

 echo "Numbers: $a !"; //What I think is good
 echo "Numbers: " . $a . " !";  //What my teacher,book and tutorials use.
 echo 'Numbers: ' . $a . ' !'; // Trick that gave a noticeable performance gain pre-PHP 4.3

?>
```

Why would one prefer the second or third way in the latest version of PHP today?

Comment: It is required sometimes, for example in arrays (e.g., `"Numbers: ".$_POST['aNumber']."!";`

Comment: You could use echo "Numbers: {$a} !";
It is considered to fast and efficient and readable though.

Comment: @SableFoste You can use curly breckets with arrays.

Comment: `why do people still split their double quoted links?` Don't care to much about this. It's just pointless to split in this case

Comment: @FakeHeal, this is true, but not always consistent.  It may produce unexpected results.

Comment: also, but that is only my opinion, it is easier to spot variable inside string that way. As most modern IDEs have different colors for strings and variables.

Comment: @SableFoste that is definatly NOT true, `"Numbers: {$_POST['aNumber']}!";` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @DaanTimmer I usually do `echo "Numbers: $_POST[aNumber]!";` myself. I'm also in the anti-extraneous operators club :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, let's say you have `$a = "apple";`, and you wanted to put it in the string `"I love ______s!"`

Using interpolation, your "preferred" method, you might try this: `"I love $as!"`, but of course this won't work.

This is why I prefer using `"I love ".$a."s!"`, as this prevents any kind of confusion. It also makes it very easy to change it to an array access for whatever reason, so it's more "future update-proof". It should also be noted that most code editors can't highlight the interpolated variable, so it's harder to find visually.

Comment: Why not just `"I love {$a}s!"` same outcome? same readability?

Comment: That might be true. Last time I've only been working with PHPStorm (jetbrains) which did highlight it.

Answer (score 3):

I usualy use the third way:

```
echo 'Numbers: ' . $a . ' !';
```

I use single quotes as much as possible because I think it looks much cleaner. When I need things like a newline in my string I usually write it seperately from the rest of the string. This also points out this "special" string a bit more:

```
echo 'Numbers: ' . $a . ' !' . "\n";
```

Also I think having variables inside double quoted strings (`"like $so"`) is unclear and you won't have syntax highlighting in many editors.

Comment: `and PHP doesn't have to look for special characters.` +1

Comment: or if you don't need the concatenated string, you just want to echo the 3 values you can use a comma as echo accepts a variable number of parameters and you don't need to add an extra operation to the "game" (the concatenation)

Comment: It's not faster! http://nikic.github.io/2012/01/09/Disproving-the-Single-Quotes-Performance-Myth.html